# Is Zoolander sci-fi?

Tags: discussion, scope

Do Zoolander and its sequel constitute as sci-fi?

There are certainly strong elements of sci-fi, including:

- Zoolander using a psychic power to stopping a throwing star from killing the Prime Minister of Micronesia
- > Having Zoolander, Derek Jr, Hansel <sup>who is so hot right now</sup> and Sting using psychic powers to catch a bomb
- > A swimsuit model with the ability to swim underwater for thousands of miles
- Large scale government and high fashion conspiracies
- > Ghosts from beyond communicating with the living

As such, does Zoolander constitute sci-fi?

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. Zoolander is clearly a documentary.

Comment: Actually Malaysia, of course.  (Though that was one of the jokes in the first movie.)

Answer (score 20):

I don't really think that Zoolander fits into the genre descriptions for Scifi.

It certainly contains *elements* that are scifi-ish but only as part of a wider fantasy universe in which male models apparently have superpowers such as "hotness" and the ability to freeze objects in mid-air when they pose.

[image]

As is usual with these edge-cases, **questions about the fantastical bits of the film are broadly on topic**. More general questions about the film should be taken elsewhere, perhaps to Movies:SE

Comment: +1 Similarly, when comedy/spoof movie [Top Secret!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Secret!) features an underwater fight in a Western-like bar, this isn't fantasy, even though submerged cowboy bars do not exist. Comedy movies often feature illogical/silly scenes for the sake of silliness; this isn't scifi or fantasy.

Comment: I think if it has to fit into a genre other than fiction or comedy Speculative Fiction might do the job.

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn What is Speculative Fiction? I thought it was a polite term for science fiction, much like "graphic novel" was for comics.

Comment: @AndresF. - *Speculative* fiction also covers things like alternative-worlds and "what-if" stories that have no discernible science content.

Comment: @AndresF. What Richard said, also covers horror and fantasy.. HP lovecraft and Robert Howard could fit into it too