# Is the Angry Birds game and movie on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Ok long story I sort of posted this question on Movies and Tv by accident (got my book marks mixed up :p) so please say nothing about the double up of the question.

But here it is... finally in the right place!

Ok they are machine making, cowboy hat wearing, egg stealing pigs and the Birds are well you know! So I would say that they are well out of the bounds of the normal and into the world of the fantastical.

But before I ask my question I wanted to know if they were on topic or not. :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BG9mplKbVwg

Comment: FYI, there's also as far as I know cartoons as well. And Indiana Jones pig with a Crystal Scull in the last Angry Birds Epic special mission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The games may or may not be on-topic

Some of the Angry Birds games (at least the first one) simply do not contain enough science fiction or fantasy elements to generally be on-topic. Narrow questions about their science fiction aspects (if any) might be acceptable, though. **The situation might be different for many individual games, such as Angry Birds Transformers, or Angry Birds Star Wars, which *are* science fiction and connected to an established property to boot, or the Angry Birds Epic RPG, which appears to be fantasy.**

That said, all video games should be on-topic at [Arquade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

### The movie is on-topic

The pigs possess technology, but nothing more advanced than what was available at the time the movie was created (airplanes and so forth). However, the birds' special powers, which are little more than mechanics in the game (and thus do not qualify it as SFF) are, well, special powers. For example, Bomb can blow himself up and create an electric shockwave in the movie, which is a clear super-power. As such, the movie is on-topic.

### The general principle

[Current site policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5119/51379) says that anthropomorphic animals *by themselves* are not enough to render a work on-topic. Though there remains disagreement, that is the current community consensus.  As such, a movie such as *The Angry Birds Movie* would have to possess additional speculative fiction elements in order to be considered science fiction or fantasy (and does).

Comment: angry birds has about 1352152 different games, including a space version, starwars version, ect. all of the games are loosely ontopic via magical birds, but a large quantity of their games are firmly ontopic.

Comment: @Himarm - Yeah, that's why I mentioned that Angry Birds Transformers or Epic or whatnot might be on-topic. I doubt the main two are, but yeah, most are on-topic as far as video games go.

Comment: Angry Birds Star Wars certainly is

Comment: [Angry Birds 2](https://www.angrybirds.com/games/angry-birds-2/) has steampunk airships and spells you can cast.

Comment: Are they all in the same universe?

Comment: @CreationEdge kinda

Comment: Ok so cool... :)